# How do I implement the TypeArgument for a Workflow Custom Activity to set a known type

Tags: generics, custom-controls, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

Trying to build a custom activity for doing REST Calls (get, post, put, delete) in a workflow library and make it generic enough to take any url, etc.

I want to be able to set a return type upon dropping this activity on the designer like the Foreach or Switch does.

How do I implement that bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that's trivial and a common case scenario within WF world.

Just make it a normal [Activity<TResult>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466009(v=vs.110).aspx) (or one of its inherited classes: [CodeActivity<TResult>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465967(v=vs.110).aspx), [NativeActivity<TResult>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd454626(v=vs.110).aspx), etc.) where *TResult* is the return type. The designer will take care of asking the user for the *TResult*'s type.

```
public class MyCustomActivity<TResult> : CodeActivity<TResult>
{
    protectd override T Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {
        // Do something and return TResult
        return default(TResult);
    }
}
```

Note that the designer will ask not only for *TResult*'s type but for any generic type specified. You might also have, for example, generic InArguments:

```
public sealed class MyCustomActivity<TInArgument, TResult> : CodeActivity<TResult>
{
    public InArgument<TInArgument> GenericInArg { get; set; }

    protected override T Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {
        var g = GenericInArg.Get(context);

        Console.WriteLine("GenericInArg: " + g);

        return default(TResult);
    }
}
```

Comment: OK great.  A Follow up question.  What if I want to pass the TResult type into a method as a type as well.  i.e. inside Execute have a method called  Blah.Go<TResult>("yeah");   How do I make the TResult resolve at compile time?

Comment: Sorry, can't understand your question. What does *pass the TResult type into a method* means? *TResult* isn't a value or instance of anything, is just a parameter. You can pass the type parameter to said method just like you wrote it: `Blah.Go<TResult>()`

Comment: yeah my problem seems to be there is a where T : Class on the Go Method of the Blah.  Which restricts me from doing this.  I'm having it removed.